# What happens if I defeat an enemy and run out of HP at the same time?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

What happens if I defeat an enemy and run out of HP at the same time? For example, if you use a self-damaging attack like [Boomerang](https://diceydungeons.fandom.com/wiki/Boomerang) or if you take damage form attacking an enemy with Thorns.

Answer (score 1):

You will die, the run will end. The game checks for your health before finishing the fight, so before you have the chance to get xp and return to the map, you'll get the death screen.

Comment: I've since learned this isn't true, at least when dealing with thorns https://youtu.be/9LNtPGID_s4

Answer (score 1):

Dying from thorns on the same turn you defeat the enemy is counted as a victory where you survive with 1hp.